# Customize a Business Component in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, xml, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf

Is it possible to customize a `Business Component (jpx)` in `oracle ADF`?

My problem is:

I'm doing a `customization project` and I need to access a `view object` from another project.

What I was trying was to customize the `Business Component`, importing my `Reusable jar` into it so I could access the other `Business Component`.

Whenever I do this I get the following error:

```
Error saving XML files - testUiModel

JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught:
oracle.bali.xml.model.XmlDomCommitException, msg=MDS-00017:
Customization instruction generated for
"adf/test/testUiModel.jpx" uses local reference(s):
"(xmlns(mds_n1=http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j))
/mds_ns1:JboProject/mds_ns1:AppContainee[3]/mds_ns1:DesignTime" which is not upgrade safe.

Exception: oracle.jbo.JboException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% on this one, but I would say this is not possible.

But if you use the SAME EO and VO packages as the original JPX, you won't be needing this customisation. Customisation of the application module should be able to pick up your components automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You, the person receiving the shared jar file, cannot edit BC components that are shared via JAR files. You *can* build new BC components based on the shared jar contents, but the user of the shared jar cannot edit it. I second Florin's comment, and add:Consider putting all the EOs into one project and share that, then have the individual developers responsible for designing/developing a given use case used that shared EO library to build the specific VOs and Ams for their use case. Also, Common VOs - like LOVs can be shared as well.